# Opportunity Owner.Email returning null in Apex

Tags: trigger, feeditem

I am trying to send emails to Opportunity owners when a portal user posts in chatter. But I can't seem to access the owner email from below Oppty query - it is returning null. However, when I query in Dev console the Owner.Email gives me value. How do I get the opportunity owner emails in apex and send a notification on insert of a chatter post?

Code snippet:

```
//Get related Opportunity Ids
  for(FeedItem fItem : (List<FeedItem>)Records){
      if(fItem.ParentId.getSobjectType() == Opportunity.SobjectType){
          opptyIdSet.add(fItem.ParentId);
          OppIdtoFdItmMap.put(fItem.ParentId, fItem);
      }
  }
  
  for(Opportunity opp: [SELECT Id, Name, Owner.Email from Opportunity WHERE Id IN :opptyIdSet]){
      System.debug('>>>Opp Owner Email: ' + opp.Owner.Email); //returns null
      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
      mail.setToAddresses(new List<String> {String.valueOf(opp.Owner.Email)}); //returns null
      mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgwideAddress.Id);
      mail.setSubject('Notification: New chatter post in ' + opp.Name);
      mail.setPlainTextBody(OppIdtoFdItmMap.get(opp.Id).Body);
      
      mails.add(mail);
  }
```

Debug Logs:

[image]

Comment: Seems to be an access issue, where are you running this code in the portal?

Comment: So we have a community portal where partner users can log in and access an Opportunity. Our User object's org wide default is set to private - is this why? But I've read Apex runs in system mode so it ignores user's permissions...

Comment: Is the class running with sharing or without sharing - if it runs with sharing it uses the running user's permissions not system mode.

Comment: @SF_newbie yes Dave is right, check if this class is `with sharing`

Comment: It is using without sharing in the class (public without sharing class FeedItems extends fflib_SObjectDomain)

My trigger is in FeedItem context and calls this class on after insert. I can get the Opprty OwnerId though. Seems like I can't traverse 1 level deeper when querying in apex.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a different approach and I realized I'm just unable to query in the User obj even when I posted as an admin in the Community Portal. Found this post
[Unable to query User object from Customer Community user](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246204/unable-to-query-user-object-from-customer-community-user) with the link to Salesforce Known Issue with workarounds. I've tried the first workaround and my query is now returning the owner.email.

Edit:
Just be careful though if you choose the 1st workaround as this sends Welcome email to the internal users - turn off the Community Welcome email first before adding Internal User Profile as community Member.

Comment: if the issue is resolved, plz mark this as selected answer (you can select own answer after set duration) so that this question is marked  as resolved., and will potentially help other in future.